# align math inside a float environment

Tags: align

I try to include a few math equations inside a float (figure), but the align environment seems not to trigger the math environment (as usual). The equations separately print ok, inside the float, latex stops and no output is produced. I obviously do not understand the interaction between floats, align and math?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}        
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{align}
    & 1 \in N
    \\ &\forall n \in N  \exists n' \in  N \qquad  &\text{($m'$ is the successor of $m$)} 
    \end{align}
    \caption{The axioms for natural numbers as given by Peano 
    \label{PeanoAxioms}
\end{table}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are missing the closing brace of `\caption`. Apart from that, I find numbered equations inside a floating environment a very bad idea.

Comment: thank you for confirming that the align environment inside a float will work. The missing closing brace was the effect of editing a MWE. The problem in the original were blank lines... - I will rethink the use of numbered equations, thank you for the comment!